# How validate data before insert to database C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, model-view-controller

I need validate data before insert to database. My website get data from excel copy this data in sql server. But now i need before that happens validate the data 
and leave a message with the errors because for the structure of the database.
I need help and some on to guide me. Im newbie Please

Comment: Did you try writing come code that would run between reading the data from Excel and inserting the data into the database? How did that code not work as desired?

Comment: First what have you tried?  You can import the file into C# if it is a smaller file, or larger you can import into a staging table, do your validation there (and even append errors to each row) and then either save or post errors back to your site.  When you save them take from staging table and save into real table

Comment: What are you trying to validate? That the data is in a specific format? That it doesn't contain naughty words? Be specific about what you are doing. Provide examples

Comment: I have not tried anything yet, I wanted to have advice and choose the best option.
Excel file has fields with text and numbers and around 1000 records. for example. 
if in the column name (varchar) someone put a number i need validate that before copy in database and tell the user.

Comment: Well then you have to write some code to accomplish that.

Comment: Would need to know the validation rules to help you.  And you need to post some code and data examples.

Comment: Hints on the code you are going to write.  Use `int.TryParse` and other numeric types' TryParse functions for numeric types.  For strings, the most common validation is for length - that's easy.  Consider using Enum.TryParse if you want to validate that a string is one of fixed set of choices (as long as the choices fit the bill for being an enum's name). Regex may be your friend here (or may be your enemy).  As mentioned below (by @FilipeRamos), `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` may be the answer to your problem

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can validate data and depending on your excel file and process you might need a combination. A simple solution you can implement since you will eventually need to create an object to hold your data will be to leverage the **`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`** namespace in the framework. This gives you both access to validation attributes like `[Required]`, `[Email]`, etc (you can extend and create your custom validations as well).

**Simple Solution** (Leveraging the framework): This is basically something MVC, EF, and other frameworks do when you add the attributes.

```
   private Tuple<bool, IEnumerable<ValidationResult>> ValidateAnnotations(object model)
   {
            var context = new ValidationContext(model, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
            var validationResult = new List<ValidationResult>();
            var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, context, validationResult, validateAllProperties: true);

            return new Tuple<bool, IEnumerable<ValidationResult>>(isValid, validationResult);
   }
```

**Note:** This is another way in which you can handle manual validation as well as attribute driven [odetocode](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx)

In terms of process; you can basically validate each row of data once you parse from excel and generate a list of valid entries for sql insert and invalid for error report.

Comment: If you don't mind extra dependencies you can also use a package like https://fluentvalidation.net/ which works pretty well but you have the option to separate where the model and validation reside. This gives you the flexibility of providing multiple validations for a single model depending on business rules.

Comment: thnks , I'll try